# Wrong order with sort command

Tags: sort, locale

How to get sort command working with data separated by "|" 
(pipe character) ?

Consider this sample file called "x" which have two fields:

```
axis-AXIS|OK
axis-AXISR|OK
axis-AXISD2X|OK
axis-AXISA|OK
axis-AXISD1|OK
axis-AXIS1RX|OK
axis-AXISR1M|OK
axis-AXISD2|FALSE
axis-AXISMD|FALSE
axis-AXISM|FALSE
axis-AXISE|OK
axis-AXISD|OK
```

My locale:

```
echo $LC_ALL
C
```

When it is sorted the character "|" seems to be part of the key producing a strange assortment:

```
sort -t"|" x

axis-AXIS1RX|OK
axis-AXISA|OK
axis-AXISD1|OK
axis-AXISD2X|OK
axis-AXISD2|FALSE
axis-AXISD|OK
axis-AXISE|OK
axis-AXISMD|FALSE
axis-AXISM|FALSE
axis-AXISR1M|OK
axis-AXISR|OK
axis-AXIS|OK
```

Specifying a field key `sort -t"|" -k1 x` nothing changes.

Comment: Am I going blind?  You say, "Specifying a field key, the assortment changes ...", but I don't see any difference in the output.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  P.S. I believe that you mean `echo "$LC_ALL"`, not `echo \`$LC_ALL\``.

Comment: Copy&Paste on typing mistake I'll fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the closing field number with `-k`, it will consider all fields starting from 1. You need :

```
sort -k1,1 -t'|' file.txt
```

Test :

```
$ sort -k1,1 -t'|' file.txt 
axis-AXIS|OK
axis-AXIS1RX|OK
axis-AXISA|OK
axis-AXISD|OK
axis-AXISD1|OK
axis-AXISD2|FALSE
axis-AXISD2X|OK
axis-AXISE|OK
axis-AXISM|FALSE
axis-AXISMD|FALSE
axis-AXISR|OK
axis-AXISR1M|OK
```

If your `locale` is not `C`, you can set it on the fly :

```
LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1 -t'|' file.txt
```